# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException - simple loop throwing this exception

Tags: java, concurrency

I usually provide working code, but in this case it is not possible. Also, this is very sporadic and even providing a scaled down may not generate the error.

From the ConcurrentModificationException threads, usually the issue is visible within Collection and associated manipulation/loop. I am hoping a small code snippet would be enough in this scenario to point out something I may be missing.

```
//This is the definition of one object being used. 
protected Map<Integer,Component> myToolBar = Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<Integer,Component>());
    :
    :
myMainToolbar = createToolBar(); ///The procedure returns a new JToolBar object
    :
    :            
Set<Integer> keys = this.myToolBar.keySet();
Iterator<Integer> iter = keys.iterator();
if (iter.hasNext())
{
    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
        Component c = this.myToolBar.get(iter.next());//<----This produces the error. 

        if (c instanceof JSeparator)
        {
            myMainToolbar.addSeparator();
        }
        else
        {
            myMainToolbar.add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the returning error :

```
  Exception in thread "Thread-546" 
  java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TreeMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
```

The Iterator isn't being manipulated.
The newMainToolbar which is being modified isn't associated with the loop iterator. ***Even though this is a code snippet, the loop is the full code.*** 
Is something being overlooked within in this code snippet?

Comment: You're using a synchronized map. Is any other thread accessing that map? Or its underlying map?

Comment: Since this is working with the Toolbar, could Java be accessing it behind the scenes? Would placing the code within a synchronized block help or would that just be masking the issue?

Comment: The toolbar doesn't seem to have anything to do with it unless you have something that modifies this map. Is there anything, anywhere, that modifies the map? And I mean the map itself - modifying the value objects does not modify the map.

Comment: Any modifications are done further up in the code. By the time it hits this section, all the adds,deletes and/or modifications are done.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, then. Are you sure none of those modifications is done inside some lambda or callback that is used by another thread in parallel to this one? At this point I have to say - either find a way to make a [mcve] of it, or you're on your own. Something must be modifying that map between the creation of the iterator and its actual use.

Comment: Since it is part of the JToolBar, is it possible Java/Gui/Graphics or some Java update/refresh could be affecting it?

Comment: Is it possible to create another object to monitor this object and do a threaddump anytime its count changes?

Answer (score 0):

`synchronized` methods only locks the object for that method call e.g. for an Iterator, it is not for the life of the Iterator. If you want to use an Iterator on synchronized collection you need to hold a lock on it.

```
synchronized(myToolBar) {
    for (Component c : this.myToolBar.values()) {
        if (c instanceof JSeparator)
            myMainToolbar.addSeparator();
        else
            myMainToolbar.add(c);
    }
}
```

NOTE: I assume nothing in this loop modifies the myToolBar otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I don't believe so as both the addSeparator() and add() calls are Java calls on the associated JToolBar and Component objects.